# Conditional format cells rule for first character ignoring leading spaces (Excel 2007)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

Is there a rule which can specify all cells where the first character is ', ignoring leading spaces?

I am using excel for macros troubleshooting, want to dim out comment cells. which start with ' but often have *multiple* leading spaces (sometimes 50+, they are indents in vba).  (I want to keep the spaces.)

I have made conditional formatting rules which start with ", [space]", ", [space][space]" etc, but that will require 50+ rules, to catch comments which are indented a long way!  (It needs to NOT apply to cells where there is a ' following any other string apart from a blank.)

[image: Example of issue]

Or, is there any way to specify *any number* of consecutive spaces, in Excel? (In Word I could use " {1,}'".)

Thanks :)

Comment: @patkim see image added to question

Comment: Try the Formula =LEFT(TRIM(B60),1)="'" in Conditional Formatting --> New Rule and then use Format Painter to apply it to all applicable cells. However if the cell has very first immediate character as ' (without any leading spaces) then Excel treats it as a special character to consider format of that cell as Text and such very first ' will be invisible to formula. You may need VBA approach if you have such instances of comment cells therein.

Comment: This is the answer- please post as an answer and I will mark it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first ' in Excel cell (without any leading spaces) is a special character  treated by Excel to consider the format of the cell as Text. You type 'Hello in a cell with very first character being ' (without any leading spaces) and Excel will treat it as Text with contents Hello. The single quote will disappear and in that sense it is likely to be invisible to a Formula.

You may have instances like word Hello immediate after ' at start of cell, or spaces then ' then Hello or even spaces then ' then spaces and then the word Hello in cells. So Formula is likely to ignore the first scenario.

You can try this VBA Macro and see if it works for you. I have tested it in Excel 2013 but your version 2007 could behave differently.  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to access VBA Editor. Insert a Module and paste the following code into it. Save the file as .xlsm.

```
Sub test1()


For Each cell In Range("E3:E7")


 If cell.PrefixCharacter = "'" Then
    With cell.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
 Else

   If Left(Trim((cell.Value)), 1) = "'" Then
    With cell.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

   End If

 End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Replace E3:E7 with the range you desire or modify it to pass it dynamically to it or modify it to select the desired range first and then run the macro.

Here's how it looks in my case when run. Let us know if your desired outcome is something on similar lines.

[image]

Comment: Actually the answer is the conditional format rule in your comment above!
I thought pasting from web and from the VBA modules into excel seemed to preserve the ', but if it doesn't I will modify your macro above to add the additional ', which is then caught by your conditional format rule (and pastes - the first ' in a cell doesn't paste into other applications).  Thank you very much!